# Generating ssh keys for 'apache' user on shared hosting

Tags: php, git, apache

I am making a git clone request from PHP using exec with rsa verification. This process seems to start ok, however, I soon get the error

```
Could not create directory 'var/www/.ssh'
```

I had thought that I had overcome having apache look to its own directory with ssh-add, however, this seems nots to be the case. My two lines:

```
exec('/usr/bin/ssh-add /path/to/home/dir/id_rsa > ssh.log.txt 2>&1');
exec('/usr/local/bin/git clone git@bitbucket.org:etc.git > git.log.txt 2>&1');
```

Is there a way to have the apache user call .git using an rsa key when you are on restricted shared hosting that won't let you touch /var/www/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use GIT_SSH environment variable:

```
mkdir /path/to/home/dir/.ssh/
chmod 0700 /path/to/home/dir/.ssh/
chown apache:apache /path/to/home/dir/.ssh/
```

create wrapper for ssh (in home dir /path/to/home/dir/ssh_wrap)

```
#!/bin/sh
$target=$1;
$command=$2;
ssh -F /path/to/home/dir/.ssh/ssh_config -i /path/to/home/dir/id_rsa $target $command
```

run

```
chmod +x /path/to/home/dir/ssh_wrap
```

create file /path/to/home/dir/.ssh/ssh_config:

```
 UserKnownHostsFile=/path/to/home/dir/.ssh/known_hosts
 StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

in your script before git clone add

```
 export GIT_SSH=/path/to/home/dir/ssh_wrap
```

this may need changing,  you need to get the idea. more info in `man git` `man ssh`

Comment: Thanks eicto - this looked so close to being what I needed but **export** is blocked from execution from PHP. Looks like I am going to stick to ssh'ing in and pulling until I can get a different host.

Comment: you can make shell script in your home directory and invoke it from ssh if you need. don't forget to set it executable or run as /bin/bash /path/to/your/script